# No such operation: HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /services/EchoUMO

Tags: error-handling, cxf, echo, mule, sample

I downloaded the echo sample for mule from internet. I have 1 java class

```
package org.mule.example.echo;

public class Echo
{
    public Echo()
    {
    }

    public String echo(String string)
    {
        return string;
    }
}
```

And an xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mule> 

 <flow name="EchoFlow">
        <inbound-endpoint address=":65082/services/EchoUMO" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.mule.example.echo.Echo"/>
        <component>
            <singleton-object class="org.mule.example.echo.Echo" />
        </component>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

When I write :65082/services/EchoUMO in my browser I don't get any good result. In my console i see this error:

```
 WARN  2013-03-04 12:08:10,713 [[sample-echo].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://echo.example.mule.org/}EchoService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /services/EchoUMO)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.URIMappingInterceptor.handleMessage(URIMappingInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
```

Can you explain what is going on for me?

When I write `:65082/services/EchoUMO` in my browser, my browser shows this page:

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body><soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>No such operation: (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /services/EchoUMO)</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: :65082/services/EchoUMO is not a valid address, so the configuration you posted won't even start. Can you clarify how you did configure your inbound endpoint?

Comment: @genjosanzo  i force clean local host because stack over flow gets mistake from localhost i wrote : localhost:65082/services/EchoUMO/echo/text/hello and i cean some codes can u help me more ? i am tenderfoot my email is: masoudy.maryam@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class does not use JAX-WS annotation therefor you get the error.

You have 2 choices:

1. Keep the current class and use [simple service](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF#BuildingWebServiceswithCXF-CreatingaSimpleFront-endWebService), i.e `<cxf:simple-service serviceClass="org.mule.example.echo.Echo"/>`
2. Add JAX-WS annotation to your POJO as explained [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF#BuildingWebServiceswithCXF-CreatingaJAX-WSService)